# Strange centers

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, origin, clipping

I have a mesh, when I set the center of the mesh to "ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME", the center seems to be located out of the object.

[image]

However, when I set "ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS", the object will ly down immediately and also behave strangely(clipping).

[image]

[image]

Comment: BTW, I use python script to operate the object, the comments are: 
  bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS')    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME')

Comment: It's a really messy geometry with lots of overlap, disconnected and unevenly distributed vertices. Probably that's the reason for the strange behavior. Do you perhaps have a simpler version of this mesh from before?

Comment: I mean, look at this: https://i.imgur.com/bG2vTcu.png Separated all those duplicate geometry and it still had 20.000+ vertices that got merged when I did "merge by distance". When you remove those main duplicate parts, "origin to volume" does get better, but I don't think this mesh is salvageable if I'm honest, It would be much easier to just model or download a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Geri and Kuboå, I will double-check the model.

Comment: What the hell is this mesh? I went into _Edit Mode_ to press _P_ > _Separate_ > _By Loose Parts_. This results in 7222(!) objects when there should be exactly 2: the mug and the liquid.